new controller creation Problem in laravel
I am new in Laravel. I have created a controller according to laravel.com but when I run this file in a browser it shows an error. how can I solve it? Laravel version 11.8.0

Target class [app\Http\Controllers\UserController] does not exist.

Controller file
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(string $id): View
    {
        return view('user.profile', [
            'user' => User::findOrFail($id)
        ]);
    }
}

Routing file
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use app\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/user/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show']);


I try various code but failed

You are using app\Http\Controllers\UserController and it should be App\Http\Controllers\UserController, see the uppercase App

A typo.Try this in your routing file i.e web.php and let me know.
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

I hope it will resolve the issue. If not then there might be some issue with autoloading.
